# Reference request on combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

I am looking for an elementary reference on combinatorics with applications in probability and if possible group theory.

Comment: Maybe you'll like the book by L. Comtet, Advanced Combinatorics, The Art of Finite and Infinite Expansions.

Comment: It's a bit vague. What kind of applications to probability?

Comment: Even tho it is backwards the title(references of group theory applied to enumeration) I think Chapter 7 here https://klein.mit.edu/~rstan/algcomb/algcomb.pdf can be a good way to see an interplay of groups and enumeration.

Comment: @md5 Elementary probability theory (urn processes, genetics.., example of generating functions..)